# D3.js: miss tick lines when zooming the svg

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I've got a problem confused me on the tick line, inspired from [Zoomable Area](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4015254/) created by [mbostock](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock). I'm using the Chrome V41 as the rendering browser.

When zooming page to be less than 110%, some y-axis tick lines are missed. Is that the browser's problem? Can anyone tell me why and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is caused by the rendering of the svg and this is browser dependent.

The lines are positioned on points that are not directly on pixels (they are float and not int). Additionally the width of the lines is set to `.5px`. These two facts cause the effect of missing lines on odd conditions.

A simple fix is to just increase the widths of the lines to `1px`.

Another fix would be to set the `shape-rendering` of the ticks to maybe `geometricPrecision`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help, Rouby. I've got another problem that may be you can help, it's about the mouse event: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29342670/d3-js-how-to-create-the-pop-up-event-when-moving-mouse-on-the-svg/29342795#29342795)