# D3.js: How to create the pop-up event when moving mouse on the svg?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

everyone. I've got one question about how to return the data.value with the "mouse" event. The following code can get the current X-Position(show on the ), while I've no idea how to return the **obj.value**.

I've checked the method used at [drought-crops](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2012/08/24/us/drought-crops.html), but still stuck on it.

Can anyone give me some ideas about it? I guess some of you have met such kind of scenario.

Inspired from [Zoomable Area](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4015254) and [Zoomable Map Tiles](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4132797) created by [mbostock](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock). (Add the following code into [Zoomable Area](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4015254) to debug)

```
<style>
.info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50px;
}
</style>
<script>     
svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "pane")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .call(zoom)
    .on("mousemove", mousemoved);

var info = svg.append("text").attr("class","info");
function mousemoved() {
//work with the x position returned, but no idea how to return the d.value
  info.text(d3.mouse(this));
}
</script>
```

Comment: `d` is passed as an argument to the handler function, so if you just add that you can access `d.value` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3902569

```
 function mousemove() {
    var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
        i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
        d0 = data[i - 1],
        d1 = data[i],
        d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;
    ...
  }
```

This is code provided by an example from Mike.

First you get the `x-value` of the scale you are using on the position of the mouse. Then a [bisector](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays) is used to get the two closest values of your underlying data. You then select the appropriate one and can display it.

If you want you can interpolate either manually between your two data points or use the `getPointAtLength` of path-elements and calculate the interpolated value used by the path.

Comment: Thanks, Rouby. `d3.bisector()` is just what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Just access the bound data as you would in any other handler function:

```
function mousemoved(d,i) {
    // do something with d and i
}
```